# Specify minimum requirement in a python project

Tags: python, github

I'm working on a project hosted on GitHub and I would like to specify a minimum version of a package required for the project. My current options:

- specify the requirement in `requirements.txt`, but from my
  understanding this file is an exhaustive list provided by pip of pinned versions of
  packages in a working environment
- specify the requirement in a `setup.py`, but this feels a lit overkill as the project I'm working on isn't intended to be published or used as a package
- simply mention it in the `README.md`

Is there a more elegant way of doing it ?

Comment: Use `Pipenv` that create pipfiles in your project that contain information about project dependencies and replace the requirements.txt file, this package manager now is used in a lot of projects recently . link to pipenv :   https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

Comment: Poetry is also an option, PyCharm now natively supports it as well.

Comment: @Midoki thanks for your suggestion, but I'm using conda and I wanna stick with it. What I'm looking for is a way of specifying a dependancy independently of the package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify it in the requirements.txt file like this. In your case you would want to set a min or max on the version of `SomeProject` as in line 2 below.

```
SomeProject == 1.3
SomeProject >=1.2,<2.0
SomeProject[foo, bar]
SomeProject~=1.4.2
```

Read all about it [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#satisfying-requirements) in the pip documentation.

Comment: SomeProject==1.3.* also

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way, thank you!